# SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, access-control, access-denied

I got error in below code...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CONTENT="https://www.abcd.xyz">
    </head>
<body bgcolor="#282c34" text="#43a199" >

<iframe src="2739.pdf#zoom=Fit" id="ifrmCast" type="application/pdf" width="100%" style="height:95vh;"></iframe>

<button onclick="ifrmLoad();"> Click Mee... </button>

<script>
function ifrmLoad() {
    alert("called");
  var iframe = document.getElementById("ifrmCast");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("canvasWrapper");
  elmnt.style.display = "none";

  alert(elmnt.innerHTML);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

No Any Solution found here...
I Tried..

- < META HTTP-EQUIV="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CONTENT="https://www.acd.xyz" >
- about:config ( Firefox )
- YQL
- and so many etc..